# AverageOfChildren in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

One of the functions being used in a code sample is `averageofchilren`.

What exactly the `AverageOfChildren` aggregate function actually does?
How can we compare this with `Avg()` function in MDX ?

Comment: please provide documentation link to this function `AverageOfChildren` - not one I know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a custom measure is created in your cube.

Using AdventureWorks try this:

**Script 1**

```
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]} ON 0,
    NON EMPTY 
    {[Geography].[Geography].[Country].&[Australia].CHILDREN} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2007])
```

That results in this:

[image]

Say I wanted to create a measure that returned the average reseller sales amount per region of each country then I could do the following:

**Script 2**

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[AvgOfChildren] AS
        AVG(
                [Geography].[Geography].CURRENTMEMBER.CHILDREN,
                [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
        )
SELECT
    { [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount],
      [Measures].[AvgOfChildren]  
            } ON 0,
    {[Geography].[Geography].[Country].MEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2007])
```

You can see from the results for Australia (211,857.58) that the AverageOfChildren is the average of the numbers returned by script 1:

[image]